# Better names for OLSON/IANA time zones

Tags: time, timezone, nodatime

We would like to convert windows time zones to OLSON time zones on our website. However the problem with OLSON time zones is that they use continents for naming instead of country names, e.g:

```
America/New_York
Asia/Kolkata
...
```

I don't think that any of our customers would expect that he/she must enter a continent name in order to find a correct time zone - and the list of time zones is much larger than that is used in windows - almost thousand. Even if a customer find out that he must enter a continent name, for example `Asia` then he must search in hundreds of time zones for all asia countries. That is very bad from usability point of view.

Is there any database to map OLSON/IANA time zone names to country-style names like:

```
America/New_York -> New York, USA
Asia/Kolkata -> Kolkata, India
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about this Olson tz data base.  Seems you should be able to write a program to parse it and extract what you need, but it will be some work.  I noticed the data desciption link is broke at https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html but this does give some similar information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I populate a list of IANA / Olson time zones from Noda Time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056759/how-should-i-populate-a-list-of-iana-olson-time-zones-from-noda-time)

Comment: Since you tagged your question as using Noda Time, please see the dup question link.  You will see that you can either filter the list to just the country you are interested in (perhaps with two dropdowns), or you can use a map-based time zone picker to offer your users a more interactive experience.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, there is no supplier for country-style names. If you want this, it is up to your efforts. Long answer: The IANA-TZDB is partitioned into regions, not countries, therefore the special form of identifiers (continent/city). From the [theory file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/theory.html):

- The tz database does not record a region's boundaries, and in many
  cases the boundaries are not known. For example, the zone
  America/Kentucky/Louisville represents a region around the city of
  Louisville, the boundaries of which are unclear.
- Be robust in the presence of political changes. This reduces the
  number of updates and backward-compatibility hacks. For example,
  names of countries are ordinarily not used, to avoid
  incompatibilities when countries change their name
  (e.g. Zaire->Congo) or when locations change countries
  (e.g. Hong Kong from UK colony to China).

Many more details can be read in this file. The administrators of tzdb have expressed the wish to reduce the count of zone identifiers and to keep out all political issues away from tzdb, see especially the wild debate in september 2013 on IANA mailing list. Identifiers following country borders would often not be politically stable.

Comment: By the way, a good source for mapping from windows time zone names to olson ids is CLDR from Unicode consortium.

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP was just looking for country identifiers, which are provided in zone.tab.

Comment: Spot on regarding CLDR data.  And Noda Time already includes it.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824).

Comment: Indeed, zone.tab is a help as providing simple map between identifier and iso-3166-country-code (without guarantee). See [link](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab)

Comment: The "theory file" link is broken (404). Fortunately, some relevant content is already in the answer here.

Comment: @Pac0 Have now adjusted the link The maintainer has just added a .html-file extension to the link.