# TimeZoneIdname based on airport code in java

Tags: timezone

i have a list of airport codes in my server.i would like to know how to get the timezoneidname(eg.., Europe/Dublin) for a airport code "gwy" which pertains to dublin? if anyone knows any specific api that does the same i would appreciate it.
iam wishing to do this in java.

Comment: Is there any public free source of such airport data? Last time I looked at IATA-page, it seemed to be subject to charge. If so then you cannot expect any free software to handle such a conversion?!

Comment: Not in Java, but you might want to review [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553371/how-to-get-timezone-from-airport-code-iata-faa) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21633069/634824), as well as .net sample I put together [here](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/6d219c48697c550c2476).

Comment: @MenoHochschild - Yes, http://ourairports.com/data/

Comment: @MattJohnson Thank you very much.