# Using SQL Server datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I am trying to store the date, time and timezone of a meeting that is set up within a tool. I allow the user to specify the date and time as well as select from a timezone list.

My issue is trying to figure out how to take all 3 parts and format it into a correct `datetimeoffset` to store.

I believe this is the format that SQL Server needs for `datetimeoffset`:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [{+|-}hh:mm]
```

My first question with this is what should the values of my timezone drop down be?

Secondly, is there a built in way in SQL Server to pass this string of data and convert it into the format needed for `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: Dates have **no** format. They are binary values. Formats apply only when converting/parsing strings. Use parameterized queries and datetimeoffset-typed parameters and you won't have to do with parsing at all

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a110d/2

Comment: Awesome, so now I just need to figure out how to generate a list of timezones with their offset value; thanks!

Comment: @SBB DateTimeOffset only includes the offset, not the timezone. Everyone except Windows (the OS) uses the `tzData` database. Check Jon Skeet's NodaTime library which handles both timezones, offsets and includes tzdata

Comment: That is what I meant, I will present a list of timezones to the user but the value will be the offset which will be used in combination of date & time to provide the `datetimeoffset`, correct?

Comment: Yes, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056759/how-should-i-populate-a-list-of-iana-olson-time-zones-from-noda-time) on how to extract the info from NodaTime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your tool can convert from time to string, convert it to the format you included. The `[.nnnn]` part is for nanoseconds. I haven't seen an application needing that level of accuracy. If you are OK with second-level accuracy, `datetimeoffset(0)` is enough.

Example:

```
DECLARE @time_str varchar(30) = '2015-01-19 7:20:00 -08:00'
DECLARE @time datetimeoffset(0) = CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @time_str)

SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, @time),
       DATEPART(MONTH, @time),
       DATEPART(DAY, @time),
       DATEPART(HOUR, @time),
       DATEPART(MINUTE, @time),
       DATEPART(SECOND, @time),
       DATEPART(TZOFFSET, @time)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, DateTimeOffset is exactly what you want.

Secondly, your select list for available offsets should come from the ISO list (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

SQL Server doesn't care if the timezone offset exists in the real world or not, it just needs to be valid.  Here are a couple samples:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp1 (dto DATETIMEOFFSET);

INSERT INTO #tmp1 ( dto ) VALUES  ( SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() ) --system timestamp
INSERT INTO #tmp1 ( dto ) VALUES  ( '2015-01-19 7:20:00 -08:00' ) --valid date, time, and offset
INSERT INTO #tmp1 ( dto ) VALUES  ( '2015-01-19 7:20:00 -08:16' ) --vaid date, valid time, made up offset that doesn't exist in the real world.

SELECT *
FROM #tmp1
```